# windbg !gcroot <address> returns no roots

Tags: memory-leaks, windbg, sos

What does it mean if !gcroot  returns an empty thread list?

```
0:000> !gcroot 0000000010817c50 
Note: Roots found on stacks may be false positives. Run "!help gcroot" for
more info.
Scan Thread 2 OSTHread 15a4
Scan Thread 10 OSTHread 1db4
Scan Thread 11 OSTHread 147c
Scan Thread 12 OSTHread 15d4
Scan Thread 14 OSTHread 9dc
Scan Thread 15 OSTHread 12a4
Scan Thread 21 OSTHread 18c4
Scan Thread 23 OSTHread 1260
Scan Thread 24 OSTHread 16c8
Scan Thread 25 OSTHread bd4
Scan Thread 26 OSTHread de8
```

I have a LOT of entries when doing !dumpheap -type System.String, but most of them return nothing as the example above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The are no roots for these objects and when the GC runs it will collect the objects.

Comment: @Brian - Agree and will fix the answer.

Comment: Not necessarily. They may be caught in a finalizer.

Answer (score 5):

If you say you have a lot of strings with no roots, it may be the case that many of them are fairly big strings (over 85k), and so they are stuck in the LOH, and so may not be collected as frequently as needed. See this topic for more detail:

[WinDbg not telling me where my string is rooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202784/windbg-not-telling-me-where-my-string-is-rooted)